# Capture group that matches a pattern unless it's a specific case of the pattern

Tags: regex

I'm using regex to parse and capture components of addresses. Unfortunately, the addresses don't have consistent formats.  I need a pattern that will capture city and state (e.g., "Seattle WA" should capture Seattle and WA separately), but should only capture the city if a state is not given but the country is (e.g., Seattle US should only capture Seattle).

I was using this

```
^([A-Za-z -]+),? ([A-Za-z]{2})$
```

which appropriately captures the patterns that I want, but obviously doesn't exclude the case of US appearing instead of a state.  How would I do that?

Comment: You might need a regex with alternation including valid state abbreviations, like `^([A-Za-z\s-]+)(?:,\s*(WA|...|...|etc.))?$`

Comment: Here is a Gist solving your problem: https://gist.github.com/PhazeonPhoenix/2008449